# VBA: finding maximum of a column with duplicates entries

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to find the maximum value of a column at a particular date. The date has multiple entries and I am trying to get the maximum value at each date:

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: This can be done with a formula.  Is VBA truly necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA. ReverseSort by date and then by Column C and then do a remove duplicates. Remove duplicates moves everything after the first instance. If you sort correctly first then that's exactly what you want.